# Javascript location.reload() in setInterval function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, setinterval, page-refresh

I'm making a chrome extension whose sole purpose is to prevent session timeout.For that I'm using this command:

```
setInterval(function(){ location.reload(); }, 10000);
```

What I'm expecting is a page refresh for every 10 seconds which is not happening.
But when I write this :

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

It is showing hello for every 3 seconds where as `setInterval(function(){ location.reload(); }, 10000);` is refreshing page just for one time after ten minutes.
What might be the error in this ?

Comment: `location.reload()` is a browser refresh; the old page is discarded, along with its running JavaScript.

Comment: But how could I acheive the above task then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use this kind of code because every client try to load all data every 3 seconds and it puts extra pressure to the server. you can make a real-time bidirectional communication. for example [socket.io](https://socket.io) can help you to make it easily. But if it isn't possible for you try this code:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href = window.location;
    }, 3000);
```